# Lua if A != (X or Y or Z)?

Tags: if-statement, lua

So I have this function that takes in an integer. But It doesn't work and I suspect that the if statement is not valid, I could not find anything on google regarding the issue, maybe my googling skills just suck.

```
if mynumber != (0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8) then
            print("Please choose an integer number between 1-8")            
end
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: "0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8" Returns 0 doesn't it

Comment: Why not test with `if a >= 0 and a <= 8`?

Answer (score 3):

Correct. That is not how you test things like that. You cannot test multiple values that way.

`or` requires expressions on either side and evaluates to a single expression. So `(0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8)` evaluates to `0` and your final expression is just `if mynumber != 0 then`.

To test multiple values like that you need to use `or` around multiple comparison expressions.

`if (mynumber ~= 0) or (mynumber ~= 1) or (mynumber ~= 2) ... then` (also notice `~=` is the not-equal operator not `!=`).

Also be sure to note YuHao's answer about the logic in this line and how to test for this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed the major problems you have, i.e, `0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8` evaluates as `0`, the rest is ignored because of short-circuit. You need to test the number with these numbers one by one.

However, there's one last trap. The condition

```
if mynumber ~= 0 or mynumber ~= 1 then
```

is always true, because a number is either not equal to `0`, in which case `mynumber ~= 0` is true; or it is equal to `0`, in which case `mynumber ~= 1` is true.

The correct logic should be:

```
if mynumber ~= 0 and mynumber ~= 1 then
```

Answer (score 1):

Etan's answer explains the behaviour as observed in lua. I'd suggest writing a custom `FindIn` function for searching:

```
function FindIn( tInput, Value )
  for _ in pairs( tInput ) do
    if Value == tInput[_] then return true end
  end
  return false
end

if FindIn( {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, mynumber ) then
  -- ...
end
```

Comment: Implementing this function over a hash is significantly quicker than implementing it over an array/list (if a bit more typing to create the search table).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. In Lua You check if two items are NOT EQUAL by "~=" instead of "!=",
2. If You compare two items in if statement, then always remember that items should return booleans, so: instead of `mynumber != (0 or 1 or...)` try something like `(mynumber ~= 0) or (mynumber ~= 1) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simple with .... (mynumber have to be integer variable)

```
if mynumber<0 or mynumber>8 then
    print("Please choose an integer number between 1-8")
end
```